# Invalid SQL Statements on "DEFINE" commands Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am new in oracle, and when I am trying to use define command, I'm encountering ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement error. This is my code :

```
DEFINE p_num1 = 2;
DEFINE p_num2 = 4;
declare
  b1 number(7,3) := &p_num1;
  b2 number(7,3) := &p_num2;
  v_cont number(7,3);
begin
  v_cont := &p_num1/&p_num2;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_cont);
end;
/
```

In which parts I am wrong?

Comment: `DEFINE` isn't a SQL*Plus, SQL, or PL/SQL keyword.  It exists in T-SQL.  I'm not completely sure that I understand what you're trying to accomplish-- why are you defining `p_num1` and `p_num2` when you already have `b1` and `b2`?  Do you want the user to be prompted for the values 2 & 4 rather than initializing the variables to hard-coded values?

Comment: I am trying to divide p_num1 by p_num2. I'm not pretty sure that I could use DEFINE values directly in my code so I assign it into new variable. I had playing the code, but it remains same

Comment: Why not `declare b1 number(7,3) := 2; b2 number(7,3) := 4;`?  What value is the additional set of variables provide you?  Are you trying to prompt users to enter values?

Comment: Yes, I think it is silly code. But this is part of PL/SQL tasks, and I'm trying to make it.
The question is can't I divide something by DEFINE values?

Comment: @Justin, `DEFINE` is a SQL*Plus command; I'm not sure why you don't think it is?

Comment: @AbidFamasya, how are you running the above code? If I run it in Toad as a script, it executes perfectly. P.S. Don't forget to put "set serveroutput on" at the beginning if you want to see the output.

Comment: @Boneist - Because I'm an idiot mostly :-)  I was thinking that perhaps the O/P was thinking about the `variable` SQL*Plus command.

Comment: @Boneist : I'm running it from Oracle XE, in SQL commands. Is it a problem?

Comment: What do you mean "in SQL commands"? Where are you typing your commands - SQL*Plus? SQL Developer? Toad? Something else?

Comment: I am using Oracle Application Express as seen here : https://apex.oracle.com/.

Comment: @JustinCave we all have a funny 5 mins every now and again! coughcough *{;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that however you are running your code, it is considering the whole thing to be one statement. In reality, there are three - the two `DEFINE`s (which are a SQL*Plus command, that most other GUI database tools have replicated) and one PL/SQL block.

If you're using SQL*Plus to run the above, it should work, as each statement will be interpreted seperately.

If you're using something like Toad or SQL Developer and you want to execute multiple statements one after the other, then you will need to run them as a script.

If you're trying to do this via some front end code (eg. C#, etc), then you're probably best off avoiding the use of the `DEFINE`s altogether and just use bind variables to pass the values across (although how that would work with an anonymous PL/SQL block I'm not sure - you'd have to look it up yourself!)

ETA:
Since you say you're using APEX, perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920211/application-express-anonymous-pl-sql-block-and-bind-variables) will be of some use.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Oracle in years, but it looks like [DEFINE only allows you to create text variables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12017.htm). You are right now dividing a Number by a Char.

You can still do it, just assigning them to '1' and '2' and then casting them to numeric in order to be able to operate with them. But it looks like this to messy to be the right approach.

Comment: So can't I divide something by DEFINE values?

Comment: Looks like they are text so dividing by text doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Oracle will do an implicit conversion of strings to numbers if they're used in a calculation. Explicit conversion is always preferred, but I don't think that's the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

```
var p_num1 number;
var p_num2 number;

exec :p_num1 := 2;
exec :p_num2 := 4;

col p_num1 new_value p_num1
col p_num2 new_value p_num2

select :p_num1 p_num1
,      :p_num2 p_num2
from dual;


select :p_num1/:p_num2 from dual;
select '&p_num1'/'&p_num2' from dual;


declare
  b1 number(7,3) := :p_num1;
  b2 number(7,3) := :p_num2;
  v_cont number(7,3);
begin
  v_cont := b1/b2;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_cont);
end;
/
```

Output

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


    P_NUM1     P_NUM2
---------- ----------
     2      4


:P_NUM1/:P_NUM2
---------------
         .5

old   1: select '&p_num1'/'&p_num2' from dual
new   1: select '     2'/'         4' from dual

   '2'/'4'
----------
    .5

.5

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**EDIT**

```
DEFINE p_num1 = 2;
DEFINE p_num2 = 4;

var p_num1 number;
var p_num2 number;

exec :p_num1 := '&p_num1';
exec :p_num2 := '&p_num2';

declare
  b1 number(7,3) := :p_num1;
  b2 number(7,3) := :p_num2;
  v_cont number(7,3);
begin
  v_cont := :p_num1/:p_num2;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_cont);
end;
/
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answers. But that's not what I am looking for. This is parts of my PL/SQL tasks that requires DEFINE to divide two variables

Comment: Why don't you explain more about your task. Is this a homework question that somehow requires you to use `DEFINE` from within Oracle APEX? That doesn't make much sense to me; `DEFINE` is a scripting command, not something you'd use when calling PL/SQL from something that isn't a script.

Comment: @AbidFamasya That makes no sense. But I've added another solution.BTW Your code snippet works fine for me.